# Ordered field: If $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$, $d>0$, $a<b$, $d<c$, do we have $ad<bc$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

In an ordered field, if we should have $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$, $d>0$, $a<b$, $d<c$, do we have $ad<bc$?

Please include the proof/counterexample.

Comment: What have you tried? How do you prove this in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: hint: in an ordered field, if $x<y$ and $z> 0$, then $xz<yz$

Answer (score 1):

In an ordered field, if < and >0, then <.

So:

$a<b$

$d>0$

$=> ad<bd$

$d<c$

$b>0$

$=> bd<bc$

$=> ad<bc$

Comment: nice! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$